# How do I configure IIS web.config to redirect domains, but maintain the target folder / page?

Tags: iis, redirect, web-config, subdomain

I need help conducting 2 types of redirects; in both cases, any destination page names should stay the same, as follows:

**Redirect #1:** Go from a sub folder to a new domain, as follows:

http://**www.mysite.com/subfolder** -> http://www.**subfolder**.com

http://**www.mysite.com/subfolder**/mypage.html ->
http:/www.**subfolder**.com/mypage.html

**Redirect #2:** Go from a sub folder to the same sub folder on a different domain, as follows:

http://www.site**1**.com/subfolder -> http://www.site**2**.com/subfolder

http://www.site**1**.com/subfolder/mypage.html ->
http://www.site**2**.com/subfolder/mypage.html

Comment: <rule name="subfolderRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^/subfolder/" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.mysite.com" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://subfolder.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>